# Showing mysql content on search

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I have a small dictionary program connected to a database. The user can add words to the database, delete words, and (in a perfect world) search through all existing words and see the definition they were looking for on the screen. That last bit is the problem. I have no idea how to search through all the existing words in my database and put the one I was looking for above the `inputs`. How to I display the result of a search?

Here's the code:

```
<?php

    $link = //here is where my database connection info would go
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

        die("Could not connect to database");

    }


    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $mysqli = //here is where my database connection info would go
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users ( word,def) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['word'])}', '{$mysqlii->real_escape_string($_POST['def'])}' )";
        $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
        header("Refresh:0");

    }

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $mysqli = //here is where my database connection info would go
        $command = "DELETE FROM users WHERE `word`='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['delete-word'])}' or `def`= '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['delete-def'])}' ";
        $delete = $mysqli->query($command);
        header("Refresh:0");

    }

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        //this is where the code would go to search the database and output the answer on the screen.

    }



 ?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Dictionary search</title>
</head>
<body>

<form class = "forms" method = "post" action = "index.php">
<input type = "text" name = "word" placeholder="Add Word...">
<input type = "text" name = "def" placeholder="Add Definition...">
<input type = "submit" name = "add" value = "Add">
</form><br>

<form class = "forms"  method = "post" action = "index.php">
<input  type = "text" name = "delete-word" placeholder="Delete Word...">
<input type = "text" name = "delete-def" placeholder="Delete     Definition...">
<input type = "submit" name = "delete" value = "Delete">
</form>

<form class = "forms"  method = "post" action = "">
<input  type = "text" name = "search-word" placeholder="Look Up Word...">
<input type = "text" name = "search-def" placeholder="Look Up Definition...">
<input type = "submit" name = "search" value = "Search Dictionary">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$mysqlii->real_escape_string` one `i` too many

Comment: Oops yeah. Haha. Any ideas on how to search through the database and output the response?

Comment: Use a select sql command and loop through its resultset and print out the results. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: SELECT def FROM table WHERE word = 'searched word'

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $mysqli = //here is where my database connection info would go
    $command = "SELECT *FROM users WHERE `word`='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search'])}' or `def`= '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search'])}' ";
    $select = $mysqli->query($command);  

  if ($select->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $select->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Word: " . $row["word"]. " " . $row["def"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks you! That helped!

Comment: @Aaronpd1 Welcome. Appreciated for your up vote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML to get the search string

```
<form method="POST" action="someurl.php">
<input type="search" name="search-string">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Code to get the data from the database (may have minor syntax errors).

```
$sql = "SELECT word,def FROM users WHERE word LIKE  '%{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search-string'])}% OR def LIKE ', '%{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search-string'])%}' ORDER BY word";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$rows = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Code to display the results in HTML

```
<?php if (count($rows) > 0) : ?>
<dl>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $r) : ?>
        <dt><?= htmlentities($r['word']) ?></dt>
        <dd><?= htmlentities($r['def']) ?></dd>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</dl>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should learn about PHP more and start learning OOP coding in PHP. Second, use HTML5 in your codes!(I don't use it in this answer, please search Google for more information about HTML5.) Third, I've updated your code according to your request but still not the best practice to follow.

`index.php` file:

```
        <?php

            $link = //here is where my database connection info would go
            if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                die("Could not connect to database");
            }

            if(isset($_POST['add'])){
                $mysqli = //here is where my database connection info would go

                $word = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['word']);
                $def = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['def']);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (word,def) VALUES (".$word.",".$def.")";
                $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
                if ($insert) {
                    echo 'success';
                } else {
                    echo 'error';
                }
            }

            if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                $mysqli = //here is where my database connection info would go

                $word = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['delete-word']);
                $def = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['delete-def']);

                $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE `word`='".$word."' OR `def`='".$def."'";
                $delete = $mysqli->query($sql);
                if ($delete) {
                    echo 'success';
                } else {
                    echo 'error';
                }
            }
        ?>

        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Dictionary search</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <form class="forms" method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" name="word" placeholder="Add Word...">
        <input type="text" name="def" placeholder="Add Definition...">
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
        </form><br>

        <form class="forms"  method="post" action="index.php">
        <input  type="text" name="delete-word" placeholder="Delete Word...">
        <input type="text" name="delete-def" placeholder="Delete Definition...">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
        </form>

        <form class="forms"  method="post" action="search.php">
        <input type="text" name="search-word" placeholder="Look Up Word...">
        <input type="text" name="search-def" placeholder="Look Up Definition...">
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Dictionary">
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

`search.php` file:

```
        <html>
<body>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    //this is where the code would go to search the database and output the answer on the screen.
    $mysqli = //here is where my database connection info would go

    $search_w = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search-word']);
    $search_d = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search-def']);

    $sql = "SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `word`='' OR `def`=''";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $rows = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) :
        $rows[] = $row;
        ?>
        <p><?php echo $row; ?></p>
    <?php endwhile;
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry for the mess. I'm at Windows OS, which is not my coding environmental. Also, please learn PDO instead of mysqli or even mysql next time ;)

Comment: Thank you! Good to know.